# Can't read my second JSON ANDROID

Tags: php, android, json

firstly thank for helping me !

I want to do a MCQ in my android project, i can load the question but i can't load one choice. To succesfully load one of my choice, i have to comment my :

```
echo json_encode(array("lesQuestions"=>$lesQuestions));
```

in my php.

To me, i can't acces my second JSON return from my php and i don't know why !

Here is my JSON return :

```
    {
    "lesQuestions": {
        "1": {
            "question": "Est-ce que Captain America gagne contre IronMan",
            "id": "31"
        }
    }
} { //for JSONLint, this is where i have a problem
    "lesChoix": {
        "1": {
            "choix": "Non"
        },
        "2": {
            "choix": "Oui"
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my PHP and i get a JSONObject with it:

```
$db = mysqli_connect($host,$user,$pass,$db);


$questions = $db->query("SELECT question, id FROM question ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 1");
$iNb = 0 ;
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($questions)){
    $id=$row['id'];
    $iNb = $iNb + 1;
    $lesQuestions[$iNb] = $row;
}
echo json_encode(array("lesQuestions"=>$lesQuestions));

$choix = $db->query("SELECT choix FROM choix WHERE id_question = $id ORDER BY rand()");
$iNb2 = 0;
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($choix)) {
    $iNb2 = $iNb2 + 1; 
    $lesChoix[$iNb2] = $row;
}
echo json_encode(array("lesChoix"=>$lesChoix));

?>
```

and here is my JAVA :

```
final JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, "http://ent-ifsi.com/Projet/Application_Android/signeCliniques_android.php",
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response)
                {

                    try
                    {
                        JSONObject lesQuestions = response.getJSONObject("lesQuestions");
                        Iterator<?> keys = lesQuestions.keys();

                        JSONObject lesChoix = response.getJSONObject("lesChoix");
                        Iterator<?> keys1 = lesChoix.keys();

                        while(keys.hasNext()) {
                            String key = (String) keys.next();
                            if (lesQuestions.get(key) instanceof JSONObject) {
                                JSONObject obj = (JSONObject) lesQuestions.get(key);
                                String signesCliniques = obj.getString("question");
                                symptomesQuestions.setText(signesCliniques);
                            }
                        }
                        while (keys1.hasNext()) {
                            String key1 = (String) keys1.next();
                            if (lesChoix.get(key1) instanceof JSONObject) {
                                JSONObject obj1 = (JSONObject) lesChoix.get(key1);
                                String choix = obj1.getString("choix");
                                lesChoixButton.setText(choix);
                            }
                        }


                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e + "",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }


                }
            },

            new Response.ErrorListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error)
                {
                    Log.e("Volley", "ERROR");
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), error +"",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }
            }


    );
    queue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
```

I hope you can help me because i'm on this problem this 2 day and i can't solve it !

Bye !

Comment: This not a valid json, check using [jsonlint](http://jsonlint.com/) for example. Also can you provide more details about your error ?

Comment: i can get into my application my String from the lesQuestions array but i can't get my different choice from my lesChoix array. thx for trying to help me. Hum, how should i use jsonlint ?

Comment: Oh okay, i get it ! So my Json is not valid because i'm trying to echo 2 jsonEncode ! but how can i do ?